# How would I combine two ArrayLists that are of a special type?

Tags: c++, arraylist

The goal of this portion of the assignment is to create specialized implementations of an `ArrayList` of `Addresses`, or `ArrayList<Address>`. We are to combine two ArrayLists of this type, but our given starter code has me a bit lost on where to start.

First, we have a templated ArrayList from class in `ArrayList.h`, along with some functions to go with it:

```
template <class T>
class ArrayList {
public:
     /**
     * @brief Add copy of item to the end of the list, growing internal storage if needed
     * @param insertItem Item to duplicate into the list
     */
    void insertEnd(const T& insertItem);

     /**
     * YOU WILL IMPLEMENT IN AddressArrayList.h/cpp
     */
    void combine(ArrayList<T>& otherList);

protected:
    /**
     * @brief Allocate new storage array double old capacity and copy
     *          existing items to it.
     */
    void grow();

    T* list;        ///dynamic array holding stored items
    int length;     ///logical length of list - how many items are being stored
    int maxSize;    ///size of array used for storage
};

template <class T>
void ArrayList<T>::grow()
{
    int newSize = maxSize * 2;
    T* tempList = new T[newSize];

    for(int i = 0; i < maxSize; i++)
        tempList[i] = list[i];

    maxSize = newSize;

    delete [] list;
    list = tempList;
}

template <class T>
void ArrayList<T>::insertEnd(const T& insertItem)
{
    if(length == maxSize)
        grow();

    list[length] = insertItem;
    length++;
}
```

After this, we have the definition of an `Address` in `Address.h`:

```
#ifndef ADDRESS_H
#define ADDRESS_H

#include <string>
#include <fstream>


struct Address {
    std::string first;
    std::string last;
    std::string streetAddr;
    std::string city;
    std::string county;
    std::string state;
    int zipCode;

    Address();

    //Accepts comma seperated line of text with fields in order of member variables
    explicit Address(const std::string& dataLine);
};
```

Finally, in `AddressArrayList.cpp` is the function we are supposed to implement. It is stated to be a "template specialization for an ArrayList of Addresses. This is defining a combine that will ONLY work for an ArrayList". My confusion begins at this point. The function should be implemented along the lines of something like `listA.combine(listB)`, and given that fact and all the code given to us already, I think I need to use the `this` pointer, but what I've tried below resulted in failure, and I don't know where to go from here.

```
// @brief Move all items from otherList to the end of this List.
// @param otherList List to be combined into this one. It should end up empty.
template <>
void ArrayList<Address>::combine(ArrayList<Address>& otherList) {
    grow();
    for (int i = 0; i < this->length + otherList.length; i++) {
        this->list[i + length] = otherList.list[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: didn't read all but `this->list.insertEnd(otherList.list[i]);` Seems like the way to go. And remove the call to `grow();`.

Comment: @NadavS I don't think ```insertEnd``` is supposed to be used for this, I get the error "no member named ```insertEnd``` in ```Address```".

Comment: I'm sorry, I meant `this->insertEnd(otherList.list[i]);`. The point was using `insertEnd` instead of manually assigning.

Comment: @NadavS Replacing ```this->list[i + length] = otherList.list[i]``` with ```this->insertEnd(otherList.list[i])``` unfortunately results in the program terminating "```after throwing an instance of 'std:bad_alloc'```" when ```combine``` is first called.

Comment: Try to understand the new solution - you want to take `otherList` and add all its members to `this`. Therefore, your loop should be fixed too. Full code: `template <class T> void ArrayList<T>::combine(ArrayList<T>& otherList) {
 for (size_t i = 0; i < otherList.length; ++i) { this->insertEnd(otherList.list[i]); } }`

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use 'insertEnd()' as NadavS suggested, but if the otherList is very long, then you may end up with calling `grow()` by `insertEnd()` multiple times, which is inefficient. To optimize this, I think you can modify `grow()` to increase the capacity only once.

```
template <class T>
void ArrayList<T>::grow(int more=0)
{
    int newSize = maxSize + (more > 0 ? more : maxSize);
    T* tempList = new T[newSize];

    for(int i = 0; i < maxSize; i++)
        tempList[i] = list[i];

    maxSize = newSize;

    delete [] list;
    list = tempList;
}
```

```
template <>
void ArrayList<Address>::combine(ArrayList<Address>& otherList) {
    grow(otherList.length);
    for (int i = 0; i < this->length + otherList.length; i++) {
        this->list[i + length] = otherList.list[i];
    }
}
```